# Wildfly 8 Session Problems in multi-virtual-host configurations

Tags: java, session, jboss, java-ee-7, wildfly

This is my setup scenario:

1. EAR application with 2 ejbs, 4 war applications
2. One standalone war application, absolute with no dependency on the ear artifacts.

Scenario for the standalone war:

1. virtual-host: config-service, at context-root, alias config.mydomain.com
2. Uses jsf templates, such that the user is always on the same page, no redirects. The pages are determined dynamically based on the user action and current state.
3. Wildfly 8 correctly determines jsessionid without any problem.

Scenarios for the EAR archives:

1. war1 at virtual-host: war1-web, at contextroot /, alias www.mydomain.com
2. war2 at virtual-host: war2-mobile at contextroot /mobile, alias www.mydomain.com
3. war3 and war4 are at default-host, with contextroot as /war3 and war4 respectively.

Problem:

When i log into www.mydomain.com everything is fine, every flow and links works fine. Now i log out (destroy current session by invalidating it and so own), and then try to login again:

What i see:

1. On my main page, i have jsessionid at path /
2. When i navigate to another page, say /account, i now have 2 jsessionids one at / and another at /account.
3. Further navigate to /account/profile, and now i will have 3 jsessionids: /, /account, /account/profile

If i logged in at say: /login, wildfly ignores jsessionid at /, and generates a new one at /login, which of course will not be available at /account, and since some of my pages can only be accessed when logged in, the state at /account says am not logged, and hence i am redirected back to /, which shows that i am logged in now.

Reason why application at config.mydomain.com does not show this issue is because i am always on the same path, no links to redirect you anywhere else, and hence everything is cool with wildfly session management.

The conetxtroots at /war3 and /war4 are webservices, so in essence, they work since currently they dont need any scenarios of session management.

I need to work with java ee7 features, and hence i cannot get back to jboss 7.1 as it has issues with most of the features i am using, including some cdi producers etc.

I am hoping this is a configuration issues, and would like to have ideas of what mistakes i am doing in my urn:jboss:domain:undertow:1.1 subsystem configuration problems.

**Update:**

I have manipulated the wildfly configurations and now everything works fine if i start form my home page, with no path constraint.

That is: if i start from www.mydomain.com/home.xhtml, i can navigate to every page, and the session created at / is reused accordingly on every relative path, no more multiple jsessionids.

However, if i start from a clean slate (using incognito mode), and jump directly to lets say, www.mydomain.com/path/another-path/page.xhtml, i get a jsessionid at /path/another-path, and subsequent navigations to different paths results into a different jsessionid (which in this circumstances is expected).

Why does wildfly generates jsessionid at these paths, rather than at /

Comment: can you post configuration of undertow subsystem?
did you configure session sharing or sso?

Comment: Why would i configure session sharing for faces servlet? In any case, if it was about different servlets, i only use jsf, which uses single FacesServlet

Comment: @ctomc how do i set up the session-sharing or sso, i have looked at the undertow subsystem schema and i dont see anything relevant on the session sharing. help on this will really be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filed an issue at jboss jira and the issue is fixed in upcoming release.

A work-around currently is to have the following in your jboss-web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<jboss-web>
    <session-config>
       <cookie-config>
          <path>/</path>
       </cookie-config>
    </session-config>
</jboss-web>
<xml>
```

Comment: This appears to be the relevant JIRA issue: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-3617

Comment: @seanf yes, i am the one who created the JIRA issue

Comment: I have two seperate WAR in deployments. Even after adding the configuration, I still get different session id. Is it necessary for both the war to be in the same EAR container?

Comment: Thats not necessary. I have long separated my wars into different application deployments, and added this configuration to every war.

Comment: I am using grails and when I try to print the JSESSION ID. It gives me different session id for different application. Is there any other configuration that I am missing?

Comment: One of the war context root is /abc and the other is /xyz (defined in jboss-web.xml) and I have added the above config in both the jboss-web.xml.

Comment: Do I need to modify any other configuration in standalone.xml ? I am using the default standalone.xml which comes with the wildfly package

Comment: I deployed my wars in EAP edition. Jboss generates a single JSESSION ID for both the appication, whereas in wildfly generates different JSESSION ID. Is it a bug in wildfly?

Answer (score 1):

To complete the answer from @maress,

If your virtual hosts has a specific domain, you need to set in  the domain of your virtual-host.
(I need this when I test my web app in localhost with a fake domain name configured in /etc/hosts)

Something like that :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<jboss-web>
    <session-config>
        <cookie-config>
            <domain>special.mydomain.com</domain>
            <path>/</path>
        </cookie-config>
    </session-config>
</jboss-web>
```